# How does total mg of medicines effect human body?

Tags: medications

Most of people are concious about taking medicines by seeing the mg level of medicines as they think that high mg of medicine can effect their body so they limit the use of medicine of high mg instead of that they ask their physicians to give them low mg medicines. So is there any effect of mg level on body?

Comment: mg is a measurement for the  mass of medication and thus the amount. The more medication you take, the larger its effects are, no matter whether they are wanted or not

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 5):

This question is fundamentally flawed as it is based on a common misunderstanding about dosage. Every medication has a different [potency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potency_(pharmacology)), which could be thought of as the # of mg required to have a clinically noticeable effect. This ranges from a tiny fraction of 1 mg to thousands of mg.

[Toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxicity) level similarly varies: drug A that is clinically effective at 0.075 mg daily might reach toxic levels with just 0.5 mg daily, whereas drug B that is clinically effective at 2,000 mg daily might not reach toxic levels until exceeding 4,000 mg daily.  There is not a standard ratio of potency to toxicity either; it depends on multiple factors and can be looked up for each medication.

Therefore the # of mg can NOT be compared between different medications. You cannot compare whether a drug is better or worse for you based on the absolute # of mg you need to take of it.

Another way to say it is that just because you only have to take 0.075 mg of Drug A doesn't mean it is better for you than 2,000 mg of Drug B.

Comment: "the same for"? I think I know what you are aimimng at but that reads like inviting misunderstandings. –– I just looked in vain for a very nice illustration, log-scale, ld50, for a huge range of substances, funnel shape, does that ring a bell for you? It's not xkcd but equally eye opening.

Comment: @LangLangC Rewrote that portion, is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, its clear now and now i got the overall perception of dosage use and mg level and i hope i will make this concept clear to other people as well!

Comment: @DoctorWhom Great answer. As a doctor, I find myself explaining this concept most days - I like your way of explaining it!

Comment: @Chris lol yes I did this literally twice yesterday.  I've tried out different ways of phrasing it and these seem to work well.  Levothyroxine and metformin are a good pair to compare.